# Docker container stats hangs

Tags: docker

Have anyone come across something like this where if you run `docker stats containerID --no-stream` that the terminal just hangs? And if you do run `docker stats` it’s all empty?

I can't seem to find any resources that address this.

Info about the environment:

- Docker Version:  17.12.0-ce
- Kernel Version: 4.4.0-1049-aws
- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- OSType: linux

[image]

Comment: What OS are you using? Can you give some more details about your environment?

Comment: Sure, 

Kernel Version: 4.4.0-1049-aws,
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS,
OSType: linux

Not sure if you need something more? @mbuechmann

Comment: Have you tried the command with sudo or are you root?

Comment: Yes, I tried that approach too. I find it very odd that this data is omitted.

Comment: We've been encountering this as well on CentOS 7.x w/ Docker 1.13 in a Openshift 3.11 env on our more dense app nodes.

Comment: I managed to solve this by completely rebooting docker (was not ideal and we lost data but had no other choice)